# How to avoid error when using "For each In Range(SomeRange)" for filling blank cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate empty cells in a column till last entry. Now the only issue I am having is in the For Each loop that the debugger points to. I tried setting it as variable name (range data type), which failed, and tried the following code to make it slightly dynamic (but still points to the same For each loop line).

The column D has 1 and blank cells. I am trying to basically fill blank cells with 0.

I am trying the user to get to select the range instead as follows

```
Sub PopulateBlankCellsInAColumn()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Lastrow As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim SelectRng As Range

Set SelectRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

'fill blank cells with 0
For Each rng In Range(SelectRng) '<==THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE. DOES, NOT ALLOW SelectRng???
    If IsEmpty(rng) Then
        rng.Value = 0
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The problem line highlighted only works if I supply range manually such as

- For EAch rng In Range("D:D")

, however this fills all blanks cell till end of the whole worksheet!

I keep **getting method range for global range failed.**

Cheers for help.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectRng` is already a range so you don't need to wrap it in `Range`.

```vb
Sub PopulateBlankCellsInAColumn()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Lastrow As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim SelectRng As Range

Set SelectRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

'fill blank cells with 0
    For Each rng In SelectRng.Cells '<==THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE. DOES, NOT ALLOW SelectRng???
        If IsEmpty(rng) Then
            rng.Value = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. After 3 hours of trying to figure it, this was a syntax problem. Thanks for your help.